# share core-data store between apps

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data

Let's say I have a pref pane and an app. Both should share data stored in a coredata store.

Is it possible to access the same file from both app or am I going to run with scissors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both have the same models, they will be able to use the same store. But having multiple applications accessing the same store could introduce inconsistencies if they are both running at the same time. You will need to plan accordingly using conflict resolution. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdChangeManagement.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001201-CJBDBHCB. You may also need a way for one to tell the other that it changed the data and it should reload.

Comment: How can one tell to other that it is changed? Is it possible without using distributedNotifications? Please see my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653687/shared-coredata-between-apps?noredirect=1#comment36329907_23653687) and answer.

Comment: @Anoop It looks like the answer you got there covered most of the possibilities. You could use distributed objects, or some more direct form of IPC such as sockets or the various items listed in that answer.